# One-to-one association involving a joined-subclass inheritance

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm stucked on a Hibernate inheritance problem while working on a JSF-based. At first, I was oriented to use a interface implemented by two concrete classes but since mapping interfaces is not possible I used an abstract class extended by the two concrete classes. In terms of code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    protected Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_company")
public class Company extends AbstractEntity {

 private Individal signer;
    private Individuo billHolder;
    private String partIva;

    @OneToOne
    public Individual getSigner() {
        return signer;
    }

    public void setSigner(Individual signer) {
        this.signer = signer;
    }

    @OneToOne
    public Individual getBillHolder() {
        return billHolder;
    }

    public void setBillHolder(Individual billHolder) {
        this.billHolder = billHolder;
    }

    public String getPartIva() {
        return partIva;
    }

    public void setPartIva(String partIva) {
        this.partIva = partIva;
    }
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_private")
public class Private extends AbstractEntity {

 private Individual billHolder;

    @OneToOne
    public Individual getBillHolder() {
        return billHolder;
    }

    public void setBillHolder(Individual billHolder) {
        this.billHolder = billHolder;
    }

    @OneToOne
    public Individual getSigner() {
        return billHolder;
    }

    public void setSigner(Individual signer) {
    }
}
```

Now I have a fourth class (named "Client") that has a One-to-One monodirectional relation with AbstractEntity:

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private AbstractEntity holder;

    ...

    @OneToOne
    public SoggettoAstratto getHolder() {
        return holder;
    }

    public void setHolder(SoggettoAstratto cliente) {
        this.intestatario = cliente;
    }

   ...
```

And Individual is a descriptive class without relations and a property, among other, called CodFis.
Now if I a query using this criteria:

```
Criteria crit = super.getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
crit.createCriteria("holder.billHolder")
   .add(Restrictions.eq("codFis", codFis));
List risultati = crit.list();

*NOTE: the code is part of a DAO. The getPersistentClass returns a Client.class, and it works perfectly with other methods in this DAO.*
```

I get this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: table name "individual1_" specified more than once
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2062)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1795)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:479)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:367)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
```

I can't figured out what's the problem. Anyone who does?

Thanks in advance.
JLPicard

P.S.
The property names are translated from my language, so their mean doesn't match exactly in english.